# Url.Action(params) adds ')' at the end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to fill Javascrtip's variable with `Url.Action()`

`var myUrl = '@Url.Action("AddFile", "File", new { type = 0})'`;

but it generates url like this:

> var myUrl = '/File/AddFile/0)';

why is `)` there?

meanwhile:

`var myUrl = '@Url.Action("AddFile", "File")';`

> var myUrl = '/File/AddFile';

Comment: you can try this way - "@Url.Action("AddFile", "File", new { type = 0})"

Comment: @PromisPatel Answer's below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Action had

`[Route("/File/AddFile/{type})")]`

instead of

`[Route("/File/AddFile/{type}")]`